# Which one is better in mongo? Putting children in an array or in a number of fields

Tags: mongodb, schema

I have a MongoDB running as a consolidating middle layer of a number of separated SQL databases and an API.

Those SQL databases share similar Article table but in different structure. Given that an Article will under a number of category and subcategory with not more than 4 layers.

Turns out that we have 2 schema designs.

`{
    categories: [...]
}`

and

`{
    categoriyL1: xxx,
    categoriyL2: xxx,
    categoriyL3: xxx,
    categoriyL4: xxx
}`

So the question is, which one is better in performance and maintainability.

Comment: The second approach seems easier to query and maybe also index.

Comment: This is what I concern. The second way is similar to old SQL schema instead of using Mongo way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the title question (better to put children in an array or in fields) pretty much always depends on your context.

In your case, it looks like we are not talking about children, but about a layered taxonomy, with a base category, then a subcategory, and so on, for four levels. I would find it hard to justify storing this as an array, as the array would imply that all members are roughly equally valuable, except for their ordering. As @Thilo points out in a comment, the field structure also makes it slightly easier to query and index.

But the most important benefit of using fields, from my point of view, is that you make explicit the meaning of each data point. If a year down the line another developer looks at a `categories` array, they'll probably assume that they are dealing with a set of labels, and will miss the layered structure of your classification. If, on the other hand, the developer looks at a set of fields, one per category, properly named, they will have a better chance at understanding your intent.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the best structure

```
{
    categories: [
        {category:xxx, type:L1}, 
        {category:xxx, type:L2}, 
        {category:xxx, type:L3}, 
        {category:xxx, type:L4}
    ]
}
```

Instead of

```
{
    categoryL1: xxx,
    categoryL2: xxx,
    categoryL3: xxx,
    categoryL4: xxx
}
```

If you have multiples categories it is better to group then in an array.

With the second example adding a new category requires you to modify the structure, that is not a good approach.