# Performance of searching Object in array in Mongo

Tags: performance, mongodb, schema

Let says there is 2 models, Book and Reference.

Given that almost every time something accesses to Book will also need some information of Reference like id and name. And querying on id of Reference to list Books are performance so frequently.

Turns out there are 2 different schema design for Book

`{
    referenceIds: [...],
    referenceNames: [...]
}`

and

`{
    reference: [{
        id: xxx,
        name: xxx
    }, ...]
}`

We know that the upper approach create a possible error that the data in `referenceIds` maybe not consistent with `referenceNames`

However, will the lower approach create performance problem when querying `id` of `reference`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which one is better in mongo? Putting children in an array or in a number of fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401087/which-one-is-better-in-mongo-putting-children-in-an-array-or-in-a-number-of-fie)

Comment: That is me. They are asking different question. This one is querying in array of object. The other question is putting things in the document itself versus in an array.

Comment: Well aware that it is your question, and also that I don't really see any fundamental difference. Both essentially ask "Which is best? Arrays or Fields". Most importantly neither gives any context as to how the data is going to be used in your application.